# How to copy row and insert it in new row below if cell contains "," and delete what is after the "," in the original cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a row and insert into a new row directly below if a cell in column D contains a ",". There is a little more that I want to do, but it is easier to show a sample with before and after of what I want.

Before

```
Jon     Junior   Male   A, X    
Pete    Freshman Male   A, X    
Tyler   Senior   Male   A, X, C    
Dave    Senior   Male   A, C, P, U
```

After

```
Jon     Junior   Male   A    
Jon     Junior   Male   X    
Pete    Freshman Male   A    
Pete    Freshman Male   X    
Tyler   Senior   Male   A    
Tyler   Senior   Male   X    
Tyler   Senior   Male   C    
Dave    Senior   Male   A    
Dave    Senior   Male   C    
Dave    Senior   Male   P    
Dave    Senior   Male   U
```

I've tried combining some ideas from past questions, but they don't seem to be working and I haven't really used VBA before.

```
Dim GCell As Range
Dim N As Long, i As Long
N = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For Each GCell In Range("D2:D")
    If GCell.Value Like "*,*" Then
    GCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ws.Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Else

    End If
    i = i + 1
    Next GCell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it thus, adjust sheet names to suit (I put the results on a different sheet):

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, v As Variant

For Each r In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
    v = Split(r.Offset(, 3), ",")
    r.Resize(, 3).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(v) + 1)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(v) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(v)
Next r

End Sub
```

`Split` converts it to an array using a comma as delimiter; by transposing it you turn it into a 'vertical' array which can be pasted in the output sheet.